# how to use bag files with ccny_rgbd

Tags: ros, ccny-ros-pkg, ccny-rgbd

[image: Rosanswers logo]

ubuntu 12.04 and fuerte

Hi,

I want to run the ccny_rgbd with the tum kinect datasets. I am not sure how exaclty to change the setting in launch files and or other files to make them work.

In both launch files, vo+mapping.launch and visual_odometry.launch, i added

```
<param name="use_sim_time"  value="true" /> 

<remap from="/rgbd/depth" to="/camera/depth/image" />

<remap from="/rgbd/rgb"   to="/camera/rgb/image" />

<remap from="/rgbd/info"  to="/camera/rgb/camera_info" />
```

and I play the rosbag file with rosbag play --clock option.

Any suggestions to get this to work

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/59842/how-to-use-bag-files-with-ccny_rgbd/) by [sai](https://answers.ros.org/users/2967/sai/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1935 on 2013-04-02

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [sai](https://answers.ros.org/users/2967/sai/) on 2013-04-03**:
Datasets publish the depth and rgb images on /camera/depth/image and /camera/rgb/image and camera info on /camera/rgb/camera_info. Now the topics are remapped in the correct way?

**Comment by [astaranowicz](https://answers.ros.org/users/4294/astaranowicz/) on 2013-04-04**:
They should be correct. This might help:  http://answers.ros.org/question/56271/ccny_rgbd_tools-launch-files-for-pr2-in-gazebo/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Because ccny_rgbd expects the depth image and rgb image from the Kinect on those certain topics, the remaps allow the topics to be remapped to the new topics.  If you want to use datasets, you would need to publish them on your defined topics, then use the remap. Not a good solution.

---

Originally posted by [astaranowicz](https://answers.ros.org/users/4294/astaranowicz/) with karma: 238 on 2013-04-03

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0